# How to pass different scatter kwargs to facets in lmplot in Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to map a 3rd variable to the scatter point colour in the Seaborn lmplot. So `total_bill` on x, `tip` on y and point colour as function of `size`.

It works when no faceting is enabled but fails when `col` is used because the colour array size does not match the size of the data plotted in each facet.

This is my code

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set(color_codes=True)

    # load data
    data = sns.load_dataset("tips")

    # size of data
    print len(data.index)

    ### we want to plot scatter point colour as function of variable 'size'

    # first, sort the data by 'size' so that high 'size' values are plotted
    # over the smaller sizes (so they are more visible)

    data = data.sort_values(by=['size'], ascending=True)

    scatter_kws = dict()
    cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap(name='Blues')

    # normalise 'size' variable as float range needs to be
    # between 0 and 1 to map to a valid colour
    scatter_kws['c'] = data['size'] / data['size'].max()

    # map normalised values to colours
    scatter_kws['c'] = cmap(scatter_kws['c'].values)

    # colour array has same size as data
    print len(scatter_kws['c'])

    # this works as intended
    g = sns.lmplot(data=data, x="total_bill", y="tip", scatter_kws=scatter_kws)
```

The above works well and produces the following (not allowed to include images yet, so here's the link):

[lmplot with point colour as function of `size`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg7g7.png)

However, when I add `col='sex'` to lmplot (try code below), the issue is that the colour array has the size of the original dataset which is larger than the size of data plotted in each facet. So, for example `col='male'` has 157 data points so first 157 values from the colour array are mapped to the points (and these aren't even the correct ones). See below:

[lmplot with point colour as function of `size` with col=sex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOLYa.png)

```
    g = sns.lmplot(data=data, x="total_bill", y="tip", col="sex", scatter_kws=scatter_kws)
```

Ideally, I'd like to pass an array of scatter_kws to the lmplot so that each facet uses the correct colour array (which I'd calculate before passing to lmplot). But that doesn't seem to be an option.

Any other ideas or workarounds that still allow me to use the functionality of Seaborn's `lmplot` (meaning, without resorting to re-creating `lmplot` functionality from `FacetGrid`?

Comment: I do not completely understand what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe it would help if you updated the question, clearly stating which columns of the dataframe should be used for which type of visualization.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is easily possible, since the `scatter_kws` are simultaneously passed over to both scatterplots which have a (possibly) different number of points. What exactly is the functionality from `lmplot` that you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle the `lmplot` with different `cols` seems to be just a wrapper for several `regplot`s. So instead of one `lmplot` we could use two `regplots`, one for each `sex`.

We therefore need to separate the original dataframe into `male` and `female`, the rest is rather straight forward.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("tips")

data = data.sort_values(by=['size'], ascending=True)
# make a new dataframe for males and females
male = data[data["sex"] == "Male"]
female = data[data["sex"] == "Female"]

# get normalized colors for all data
colors = data['size'].values / float(data['size'].max())
# get colors for males / females
colors_male = colors[data["sex"].values == "Male"]
colors_female = colors[data["sex"].values == "Female"]
# colors are values in [0,1] range


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9,4))

#create regplot for males, put it to left axes
#use colors_male to color the points with Blues cmap
sns.regplot(data=male, x="total_bill", y="tip", ax=ax1, 
            scatter_kws= {"c" : colors_male, "cmap":"Blues"})
# same for females
sns.regplot(data=female, x="total_bill", y="tip", ax=ax2, 
            scatter_kws={"c" : colors_female, "cmap":"Greens"})
ax1.set_title("Males")
ax2.set_title("Females")
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_xlim([0,60])
    ax.set_ylim([0,12])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That didn't occur to me and it's a really good workaround